# Maven using pomInclude

Tags: java, maven

I am completely new baby into Maven and got stuck on [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_build_automation.htm).

There is an element pomInclude which is used for including another POM files.
When I build bus-core-api with command

```
mvn package -U
```

it just works for current project. The others are not called during the build.

pom.xml in bus-core-api:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>bus-core-api</groupId>
<artifactId>bus-core-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.6</version>
  <configuration>
     <debug>true</debug>
     <pomIncludes>
        <pomInclude>app-web-ui/pom.xml</pomInclude>
        <pomInclude>app-desktop-ui/pom.xml</pomInclude> 
     </pomIncludes>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
     <execution>
        <id>build</id>
        <goals>
           <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
     </execution>
  </executions>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
  </project>
```

Part of output:

`[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to c:\apache-maven-3.3.3\bus-core-api\target\clas
ses`

The others are missing. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient version of Maven-Invoker-Plugin (2.0.0) is the current version...

Comment: Ok I will try to change to 2.0. Missing is the compilation for the included modules 'app-web-ui' and app-desktop-ui. According to the tutorial they should be called and compiled according to the specified POM. This is the problem. I just receive compilation in the folder bus-core-api. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

[`pomIncludes`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/run-mojo.html#pomIncludes) is an element configuring the [`maven-invoker-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/). Quoting from the documentation, this parameter is used to:

> Include patterns for searching the integration test directory for projects.

What this means is that during integration testing of your project, Maven will run both the `app-web-ui` and `app-desktop-ui` projects and output the result to the command line.

The [`run`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/run-mojo.html) goal of that plugin binds by default to the Maven phase `integration-test`. Since you did not specify a phase, it keeps that default. Looking at the [lifecyle reference](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html), you can see that the `integration-test` phase comes *after* the `package` phase. Therefore, when you run `mvn package`, Maven does not execute the `integration-test` phase, hence the plugin is never invoked.

If you want to invoke that phase, you can run `mvn install` or `mvn verify` (or any phase that comes after the `integration-test`, this phase included).

Another solution would be to specify another phase inside the configuration of the `maven-invoker-plugin` (like `test`), but I recommend that you keep the default.

Comment: I invoked both phases and no changes has been made. The output is almost the same. The included modules are not compiled (called).
Shortened output:
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to c:\apache-maven-3.3.3\bus-core-api\target\clas
ses

Comment: May I miss something in the folders to be compiled? [INFO] No projects were selected for execution.
**I just defined pom.xml files and no java source,etc..** Can it be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'am following the same tutorial and stucking in the same problem. After some hours surffing on the web I find this question, so I start reading  @Tunaki resources [pomincludes](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/run-mojo.html#pomIncludes). And now I can obtain the three jars (app-desktop-ui-1.0.jar, app-web-ui-1.0.jar and bus-core-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar). To do that, first, I create a folder inside src called 'it' and inside it move app-desktop-ui and app-web-ui projects. Based on @Tinaka comments I run the commands `mvn install` and `mvn verify` then it works for both. But the output on the cli is different that is showed on tutorial.

```
[INFO] --- maven-invoker-plugin:2.0.0:run (build) @ bus-core-api ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[WARNING] Filtering of parent/child POMs is not supported without cloning the projects
[INFO] Building: app-desktop-ui\pom.xml
[INFO] ..SUCCESS (3.0 s)
[INFO] Building: app-web-ui\pom.xml
[INFO] ..SUCCESS (3.1 s)
```

So, I'm also new in Maven, but I think the tutorial omits some steps and also can be differences on maven implementation since the tutorial was made.